# Type event time in hours minutes and seconds

Tags: cypress

I have a simple form on the page that should take datetime values to the second.

```html
<form>
  <label for="eventNotificationTime">Event time (date and time):</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="eventNotificationTime" name="eventNotificationTime">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I try to test it I get an error

> **CypressError**
> Typing into a datetime input with cy.type() requires a valid datetime with the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, for example 2017-06-01T08:30. You passed: 2022-08-03T09:09:09

How do I enter a time containing seconds?

Test:

```js
cy.get('#eventNotificationTime').clear().type('2022-08-03T09:09:09')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue [Type into datetime-local input: seconds not accepted #22884](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22884)

The issue has been resolved in the latest release v10.4.0 (Aug 2 2022).

If you upgrade to this version, you should be able to pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add step="1" to achieve it:

```
<input type="datetime-local" step="1" id="eventNotificationTime" name="eventNotificationTime" />
```